# Why is the socket being blocked from receiving, while I sleep on another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have a simple socket listener application. It needs to be able to receive requests and give a response and also send requests itself and receive the responses for them.

As soon as my application starts, it will start receiving in **a separate thread** and send a response. This part works fine.

However when **I send requests** through the `SendRequest()`-Method, I need to filter incoming responses, so the correct responses go to the correct requets earlier made. I do this (as seen in code below) with the class `ResponseHandler`, which lets me register a request and in return notifies my registered request, as soon as the correct response came in. A placed request should however time out after 10 seconds, so I used a `CountdownEvent`, which waits these 10 seconds, but releases earlier, if the response came in earlier.

**Problem:** My `CountdownEvent` waits always the whole 10 seconds and only after that, the thread, where I receive messages will continue and thus receive the response. **How is this possible, when I receive on a different thread?**
I would think, that my program continues to receive in that separate thread, even when the `CountdownEvent.Wait()` is active.

Note: The awaited response really comes back instantly after I placed the request as seen with the NetworkTool WireShark. So the timeout is not correct.

> **Edit:** In a simple WPF-Application, where the SendRequest() is called from a button, it works. Unfortunately, this means my big program is the problem.

**Service:**

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly ResponseHandler _responseHandler;
    private readonly SyncSocketServer _serverSocket;

    private static readonly int ServerPort = 9090;

    public Service()
    {
        _responseHandler = new ResponseHandler();

        _serverSocket = new SyncSocketServer(ServerPort);
        _serverSocket.StartListening();
        _serverSocket.DataReceived += ServerSocket_DataReceived;
    }

    public void ServerSocket_DataReceived(object sender, string message)
    {
        // Here I left irrelevant code out: Originally, I check here,
        // whether the message is a request or response and so on, and 
        // I only forward the message to the _responseHandler, if it is
        // indeed a response. If it is a request I send an answer.

        string messageId = GetIdFromMessage(message);
        _responseHandler.DataReceived(messageId, message);
    }

    public void SendRequest(string message)
    {
        string messageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string request = CreateRequest(messageId, message);

        _responseHandler.Register(messageId);
        _serverSocket.Send(request);
        string response = _responseHandler.WaitForResponse(messageId);

        Debug.WriteLine("I got the correct response: " + response);
    }
}
```

**SyncSocketServer:**

```
public class SyncSocketServer
{
    public event EventHandler<string> DataReceived;

    private const int BufferSize = 1024;
    private const string EndDelimiter = "\n";

    private Socket _listenerSocket;
    private Socket _client;
    private string _data;
    private Byte[] _buffer;

    private readonly int _port;

    public SyncSocketServer(int port)
    {
        _port = port;
        _buffer = new Byte[BufferSize];
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[3];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, _port);

        _listenerSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        _listenerSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        _listenerSocket.Listen(5);

        _client = _listenerSocket.Accept();
        Debug.WriteLine("Local socket opened on: {0}", _listenerSocket.LocalEndPoint);

        StartReceiving();
    }

    private void StartReceiving()
    {
        Thread d = new Thread(() => {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            while (true)
            {
                _data = null;

                while (true)
                {
                    int bytesReceived = _client.Receive(_buffer);
                    _data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer, 0, bytesReceived);

                    if (_data.IndexOf(EndDelimiter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
                        break;
                }

                Debug.WriteLine("Message received:" + _data);
                OnDataReceived(_data);
            }
        });
        d.Start();
    }

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        byte[] bytesMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + EndDelimiter);
        _client.Send(bytesMessage);
        Debug.WriteLine("Message sent: " + message);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataReceived(string data)
    {
        EventHandler<string> handler = DataReceived;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, data);
    }
}
```

**ResponseHandler:**

```
public class ResponseHandler
{
    private const int WaitForResponseTimeout = 10000;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, PendingRequest> _pendingRequests;

    public ResponseHandler()
    {
        _pendingRequests = new Dictionary<string, PendingRequest>();
    }

    public void DataReceived(string messageId, string response)
    {
        _pendingRequests.TryGetValue(messageId, out var pendingRequest);

        if (pendingRequest == null)
            Debug.WriteLine("Received response for request, that has been removed");
        else
        {
            pendingRequest.ResponseReceived(response);
            _pendingRequests.Remove(messageId);
        }
    }

    public void Register(string messageId)
    {
        _pendingRequests.Add(messageId, new PendingRequest());
    }

    public string WaitForResponse(string messageId)
    {
        _pendingRequests.TryGetValue(messageId, out var pendingRequest);

        if (pendingRequest == null)
            return null;

        pendingRequest.Await();
        return pendingRequest.Response;
    }

    private class PendingRequest
    {
        public string Response { get; private set; }

        private readonly CountdownEvent _countdownEvent;

        public PendingRequest()
        {
            _countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(1);
        }

        public void Await()
        {
            // Here, the current thread gets blocked, but
            // I expect, that the thread, where I receive
            // would continue receiving
            _countdownEvent.Wait(WaitForResponseTimeout);
        }

        public void ResponseReceived(stringresponse)
        {
            Response = response;
            _countdownEvent.Signal();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plaster all critical points with log output. Check what happens when ... Even if you start waiting after the CountDownEvent has been signaled, it should return immediately... very odd.

Comment: @Fildor, That's what I found, too. I'm debugging since yesterday, also with logs and I don't get it, must be missing something so simple. I currently try to build the most simple program, where this problem occurs.

Comment: An [mcve] would be awesome, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** is actually the false assumption, that firing an event, like I did below, would result in a fire and forget:

```
protected virtual void OnDataReceived(string data)
{
    EventHandler<string> handler = DataReceived;

    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, data);
}
```

In the function `StartReceiving()`, where I receive data and forward it to the subscribers, it would pause at the call, that fires the event and wait for all subscribers to finish their work (which includes, of course, waiting 10 seconds for the response). This leads to the fact, that my receiver-thread, waits for the other thread.

---

**The solution** is, to implement the call, so it will do a fire and forget:

```
protected virtual void OnDataReceived(string data)
{
    EventHandler<string> handler = DataReceived;

    if (handler != null)
        handler.BeginInvoke(this, data, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, your `PendingRequest` and `ResponseHandler` classes are being accessed from different threads. So, there are a couple of things you need to do, for the sanity of your program:

a) Make sure that when you are adding and removing requests from your pending requests dictionary, you get a lock, because you are simultaneously accessing a shared datastructure from different threads. Otherwise you can corrupt your datastructure.

b) Your more immediate problem is the `Await()` method in `PendingRequest`. You are calling `CountdownEvent.Wait()` without verifying if your response is already set. If your response is already set, it would mean that you would wait for 10 seconds before you process it. This can happen if your response arrives, even before you invoke `CountdownEvent.Wait()`. In that case, `CountdownEvent.Signal()` will just be ignored. You should change the `PendingRequest.Wait()` as follows:

```
while (Response is not set) {
      CountdownEvent.Await();
}
```

Also, doesn't your `CountdownEvent.Wait()` semaphore require a mutex to be passed to it ? Remember that your `Response` object is being shared between threads. This is the general paradigm for using the wait() method:

```
mutex.lock();
while (Response is not set) {
          CountdownEvent.Await(mutex);
    }

// Do your stuff, since your condition is satisfied
mutext.unlock();
```

Comment: a) I have to look into this proposition.
b) This is not the case. As is, if `Wait()` gets called after `Signal()`, resulting in the countdown being already 0, the `Wait()` will immediately return and not wait the timeout, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: But when I use the mutex to block while I wait, would that not exactly result in what I **don't** want, i.e. that I can't update the PendingRequest, while the 10 seconds are being waited?

Comment: Conditional variables relinquish the lock inside wait () before the execution of the calling thread pauses, and reacquires the lock when woken up by a timeout or calling of signal() method, before returning from the wait() method.